# PHP daily disable / enable buttons

Tags: php, button, time

I'm creating simple game "Advent calendar" when everyday from 3 of December to 23 of December people will click on current day and can win prizes. All days will be clickable (buttons), so I have problem. I need to make that for example 3 of December people can click only on current (3) day and other days would be disabled. So idea to make that everyday unlocked (enabled) 1 button. How to make that? Possible with timers or etc?

Thank in Advance

Comment: why not just do based on the time of the request? after all, the server always knows the current date...

Comment: Very common description. What you have for the user - html page? Or javascript widget of calendar?

Comment: Thank you for answers. @Rowland Shaw and how should look like code with time request? How can I enable button by current day?

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas try my code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?PHP
$info = getdate();
$date = $info['mday'];

for($i=1;$i<=30;$i++)
{
  if($i==$date)
  {
    echo "<input type='button' value='".$i."' />";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<input type='button' value='".$i."' disabled />";
  }
  if($i%5==0)
  {
    echo "<br/>";
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I got code commented (grey code) from this line: `Echo "<input type='button'>"` I uploaded this code here [link](http://eurokos.lt/under20/button.php) but it's blank page.

Comment: Maybe in this line `Echo "<input type='button'>".$1."</input>";` instead .$1. I need to change something?